# Setting textblock margin based on content size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to show the overall progress of current playing song in below format.

hh:mm:ss / hh:mm:ss  ---> current time in hh:mm:ss / total time in hh:mm:ss

```
<Border Margin="30,0,20,0" Name="NowPlayingScurbberPanel" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="NowPlayingButtonPanel" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
                                    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=ShouldProgressBarBeVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" MinHeight="40">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock x:Uid="NowPlayingCurrentMediaTimeText" Margin="0,0,80,30" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMediaTimeCurrent}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                            <TextBlock x:Uid="slash" Margin="0,0,60,30" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Text=" / " HorizontalAlignment="Right"  />
                                            <Slider x:Uid="NowPlayingScrubber" Margin="0,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaScrubberStyle}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NowPlayingScrubber" Value="{Binding Path=ProgressBarPercentage, Mode=TwoWay}" DragStarting="OnScrubberDragStarted" DropCompleted="OnScrubberDragCompleted" ValueChanged="OnScrubberDragDelta" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ScrubberEnabled}"  />
                                            <TextBlock x:Uid="NowPlayingTotalMediaTimeText" Margin="60,0,0,30" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMediaTimeTotal}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
```

Things are working fine if total and current played time in less than an hour but when it cross more than a hour than "Slash" overlap with total time. If i give additional margin then content with less than an hour time looks bad.

How can i give margin  based on content length or is there any better solution to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the code behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void aTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTextBlock.Margin = new Thickness(10 + aTextBox.Text.Length * 2, 0, 0, 0);
        aTextBlock.Text = aTextBox.Text;
        aTextBox.Width = 100 + aTextBox.Text.Length * 2;
        aTextBlock.Width = 100 + aTextBox.Text.Length * 2;
    }
}
```

`<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox x:Name="aTextBox" Width="100" Height="30" TextChanged="aTextBox_TextChanged" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="aTextBlock" Width="100" Height="30" Text="some text" />
</StackPanel>`

Comment: I have to retain other margin values and need to set specific once only

Comment: You should never do this in the code behind - thats probably the worst way you could possibly do this. There is not a single reason to add UI styling in code behind, this is very bad practice and will cause a maintenance headache

Comment: Never say never. Some things can not be done in xaml. For example what if the user needs to dynamically create n number of UI elements at runtime. Can't do that in xaml. Yes maybe you could create a thousand UI elements and unhide them at runtime, but that sounds like a maintenance night mirror.

Comment: @GabrielWorley - In that instance there would certainly be some ViewModel collection or something which would indicate some information for these objects, and there is your binding to get the XAML to generate them. There are certain UI manipulations you may wish to do, but these again should not be done in code behind, simply create a behaviour for them and then your code becomes focused and reusable also. But I personally don't believe styling should ever sit there.

Comment: @MartinGrundy - In that instance the MVVM pattern starts to break down. You now have a collection in your ViewModel that has information about the View. The MVVM pattern is to support graphic designers that are paid less, not so much code reusability. It amazes me the trouble programmers will go through to avoid code behind, and for what? Are there even graphic designers on their team? If programs did not have to support graphic designers who knows what kind of patterns could have developed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak your layout slightly. Depends how you want it to look exactly, do you want it to overlay or be at the side of the slider?

Something like this will put the timers first and then the progress bar but you should be able to tweak to how you wish.

```
<Border Margin="30,0,20,0" Name="NowPlayingScurbberPanel" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="NowPlayingButtonPanel" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=ShouldProgressBarBeVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" MinHeight="40">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Uid="NowPlayingCurrentMediaTimeText" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMediaTimeCurrent}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock x:Uid="slash" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Text=" / " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" />
            <TextBlock x:Uid="NowPlayingTotalMediaTimeText" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMediaTimeTotal}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
            <Slider x:Uid="NowPlayingScrubber" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaScrubberStyle}" x:Name="NowPlayingScrubber" Value="{Binding Path=ProgressBarPercentage, Mode=TwoWay}" DragStarting="OnScrubberDragStarted" DropCompleted="OnScrubberDragCompleted" ValueChanged="OnScrubberDragDelta" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ScrubberEnabled}" Grid.Column="3" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

This could be further simplified by using a single `TextBlock` with a `Run` E.G.

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="NowPlayingCurrentMediaTimeText" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource NowPlayingMediaTimeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" > 
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMediaTimeCurrent}"/> 
            <Run Text=" \ "/> 
            <Run Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedMediaTimeTotal}"/>
 </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need a  Value Converter to get the margin exactly how you want it.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox x:Name="aTextBox" Width="100" Height="30" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="aTextBlock" Width="100" Height="30" Text="some text" 
               Margin="{Binding ElementName=aTextBox, Path=Text.Length, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```